# How to get request id and session id for API header request

Tags: php, api, session

I try to get API request using, but the problem is, header request need request id and session id and i dont know how to get it.

[example from documentation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3V6sg.png)
[definition of request & session id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cx0k.png)

this is token (used for request too)

```
{
  access_token: "a2155617-ff2e-2646-80e5-bdc12b3666c1",
  token_type: "bearer",
  refresh_token: "0ef2a661-6ab8-4dbc-a535-7e5e2a7c4ceb",
  expires_in: 14588,
  scope: "read write trust"
}
```

this is my code for generate request id.

```
function guidv4()
{
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid') === true)
        return trim(com_create_guid(), '{}');

    $data = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
    $data[6] = chr(ord($data[6]) & 0x0f | 0x40); // set version to 0100
    $data[8] = chr(ord($data[8]) & 0x3f | 0x80); // set bits 6-7 to 10
    return vsprintf('%s%s-%s-%s-%s-%s%s%s', str_split(bin2hex($data), 4));
}
```

Can someone tell me how i get request id & session id like the example?

Comment: What are you using to post to the API?

Comment: i try using postman sir, but dont know what must i fill for request and session id field @dontanios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postman, you can use POST and include the values in the form-data in the Body.

[image]

Run this updated code in a PHP file

```
function guidv4()
{
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid') === true)
        return trim(com_create_guid(), '{}');

    $data = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
    $data[6] = chr(ord($data[6]) & 0x0f | 0x40); // set version to 0100
    $data[8] = chr(ord($data[8]) & 0x3f | 0x80); // set bits 6-7 to 10
    echo vsprintf('%s%s-%s-%s-%s-%s%s%s', str_split(bin2hex($data), 4));
}

guidv4();
```

Comment: run the function for second times for fill request and session id?

Comment: Yes, it will give a different output.

Comment: already try but the response is 

{
    "requestId": "",
    "errorMessage": null,
    "errorCode": "500",
    "success": false,
    "value": null
}

Comment: Show me your full request

Comment: done sir, thanks for tips run my function for second times, problem solved.

fail because i forgot fill the mandatory parameter.